# java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected method call InquiryRequest.getPIN():

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I'm new to JUnit stuff, I am stuck with an error message:

> java.lang.AssertionError:
>
> ```
>   Unexpected method call InquiryRequest.getPIN():
>   at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
>   at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
> ```

could anyone let me know if anything is wrong here...

```
    ParticipantSummary summary = new ParticipantSummary();
    EasyMock.expect( inquiryRequest.getPIN() ).andReturn( "1060720" ).anyTimes();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" );
    Date date = new Date();
    EasyMock.expect( inquiryRequest.getTradeDate() ).andReturn( date ).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect( objectFactory.createRetrieveRetirementVintages() ).andReturn( rtvint );
    EasyMock.expect( guarnteecontrol.prepareServiceRequest( inquiryRequest ) ).andReturn( rtvint );
    //      EasyMock.expectLastCall();
    EasyMock.expect( objectFactory.createRetrieveRetirementVintages() ).andReturn( rtvint );

    EasyMock.expect( webServiceESBSupport.jaxbESBSendAndReceive( EasyMock.isA( String.class ), EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.isA( String.class ) ) ).andReturn( retrieveRetirementVintagesResponse ).anyTimes();

    EasyMock.expect( inquiryServiceControl.retrieveRetirementVintages( rtvint ) ).andReturn( retrieveRetirementVintagesResponse );

    ParticipantSummary participantSummary = guarnteecontrol.retrieveAccumulationByVintageSummary( inquiryRequest ); //EasyMock.expectLastCall(); ems.replayAll();

    Assert.assertNotNull( participantSummary );
    //Assert.assertEquals( summary, participantSummary );
}
```

prepareServiceRequest method

```
org.tiaa.transact.generated.jaxb.inquiry.ObjectFactory objectFactory = new org.tiaa.transact.generated.jaxb.inquiry.ObjectFactory();
        org.tiaa.transact.generated.jaxb.inquiry.RetrieveRetirementVintages retirementVintages = objectFactory.createRetrieveRetirementVintages();

        if( ( inquiryRequest ) != null )
        {
            if( ( inquiryRequest.getPIN() ) != null )
            {
                retirementVintages.setPIN( inquiryRequest.getPIN() );
            }
            if( ( inquiryRequest.getTradeDate() != null ) )
            {
                Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); //retirementVintages.setTradeDate(
                TPDateUtil.convertDatetoXMLGregorianCalendar( inquiryRequest.getTradeDate() );
                //retirementVintages.setTradeDate(( inquiryRequest.getTradeDate() );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call replay for your mocks.

```
EasyMock.replay(inquiryRequest, objectFactory, guarnteecontrol, webServiceESBSupport, inquiryServiceControl);
```